# Combox with fill-in option

Tags: wpf

I want to add to WPF Form a ComboBox which is bound to a datasource (in my viewmodel). But besides from the choices in my viewmodel I would also like to add the option of allowing a fill-in value.

How could I achieve something like that in XAML?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is turn on `isEditable`.  I'm assuming that you also want to have the new value added to your datasource.  If that is true then you will have to do some code since this is not possible with pure xaml.  [Here](http://dotbay.blogspot.com/2009/04/building-editable-combobox-for-wpf.html) is an example of how to do this.